# App processor usage increasing over time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, oop, core-graphics

I have been struggling with this problem for over one month trying to to figure out what is causing it with no solution. Since the code is pretty long i wouldn't be able to post it here.

Basically i have made drawing app. When you dubble tap the screen the screen and everything will reset, almost like I am reloading the view. When i reset the scene the processor usage will go down to around 9%, but then when i start drawing again the processor usage will go up to where I last ended. So say for example i draw and image and the processor power goes up to 50%, then dubble tap to reset the view to what is what from the beginning it will go down to 9%. Then when i start drawing again it will go up to 50%, and next time 60%,70% etc.

Maybe it is hard for you to see what is causing the problem due the lack of information so I could send my source code if someone is interested helping me by PMing me.

```
   greentimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self      selector:@selector(movement2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 -(void)movement2{
static int intigrer;
    intigrer = (intigrer+1)%3;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 568));
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:rekked];
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 8.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, r12, g12, b12, 1);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    if (intigrer == 1 && integrer2 < greenran - greenran2) {
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, greentmporary.x, greentmporary.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, greenpoint1.x, greenpoint1.y);
    }
    green.center = greenpoint1;
        if (integrer2 < greenran - greenran2) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, greentmporary.x, greentmporary.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, greenpoint1.x, greenpoint1.y);
        }
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    [drawImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  //  [self updatePoint2:YES];
    static BOOL yes;
    if (!yes) {
        [self.view insertSubview:drawImage atIndex:0];
        yes = YES;
    }
    ctx = nil;
    }
```

Comment: Is this when using the simulator or iphone? Also, Are you using UITouch?

Comment: no, this only happens on my iphone. I don't know if i use UItouch.

Comment: What frameworks are you using?

Comment: quartzcore and AVfoundation

Comment: Please post the code your using to draw.

Comment: Okey I have done it now

Comment: `CGPathMoveToPoint(path...` This makes no sense, since you have no variable called `path`. Show us your _real_ code.

Comment: You also have no variables called `integrer2` or `greenran` so how can you be using those names? This is not your real code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release your CGPaths and CGImages

```
CGPathRelease(path);
CGImageRelease(image);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Comment: And how does that affect _processor_ usage?

Comment: And where does he `Create` or `Copy` the path, image, and context you want him to release?

Comment: It could still affect it. Also when do you invalidate the timers?

Comment: No. He did not `Create` or `Copy` any path, image, or context. If he released them he would crash.

Comment: Well...but...yeah. Could it be that the timers are stacking?

Comment: thank you it actually worked by by releasing the context. But i couldn't release the imageContext. How do i do that?

Comment: UIGraphicsEndImageContext() is what releases the the imagecontext.

Comment: I'm thinking that your timers are stacking. Can I see more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are making `self.view` more complex by each fire of the timer because you keep adding subviews to it.  So the complexity of your scene increases each time its rendered until its completely reset.  I could not really follow all your code, to be honest, as I am not familiar with what you are trying to achieve.

I think an approach to solving the problem is to run your program with Instruments with the Profile option (instead of doing a 'Run').  Select the 'Automation' template.
There is a way to issue logElementTree() on your running program and it gives a dump of the UIView hierarchy with images.  There are lots of good articles on it, e.g.
http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/05/uiautomation-an-introduction.html